# How do I stop my slideshow from affecting other elements on the page

Tags: html, css

My slideshow div is paced above my header nav in HTML to create a fullscreen slideshow but all the elements on my page are fading with my slideshow, how do I prevent that?

Thank you

I'm new at this, so I'm not sure if the layout is correct or not. 

`enter code here`

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
"use strict";       
   var scroll_start = 0;
   var startchange = $('#about');
   var offset = startchange.offset();
   $(document).scroll(function() { 
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
          $('#header').css('background-color', '#3A3939');
       } else {
          $('#header').css('background-color', 'transparent');
       }
   });
});

var currentBackground = 0;

var backgrounds = [];

backgrounds[0] = 'images/pic3.png';

backgrounds[1] = 'images/pic2.png';

backgrounds[2] = 'images/pic1.png';

backgrounds[3] = 'images/pic4.png';

function changeBackground() {

    currentBackground++;

    if(currentBackground > 3) currentBackground = 0;

    $('.slideshow').fadeOut(900,function() {
        $('.slideshow').css({
            'background-image' : "url('" + backgrounds[currentBackground] + "')"
        });
        $('.slideshow').fadeIn(1000);
    });


    setTimeout(changeBackground, 3500);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    setTimeout(changeBackground, 3500);  

}); 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="home">
<div class="slideshow">
<div id="header">
 <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="styledimg"></div>
</nav>
</div>
<div id="head-soc">
<div id="linkedin-icon"><a href="http://linkedin.com/pub/titus-jackson/2/a2b/939">Linkedin</a></div>
<div id="youtube-icon"><a href="http://youtube.com/titusishmael">Youtube</a></div>
<div id="facebook-icon"><a href="http://facebook.com/titusjackson1">Facebook</a></div>
</div> 
<div class="content">
<p>Create, Collaborate, Innovate</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="about">
<div class="wrapper">
<h4>Titus Jackson</h4>
<p>Film Maker ~ Screen Writer ~ Editor</p>
</div>
<img src="images/Titus-Jackson1.jpg" alt="Titus Jackson" width="425" height="365" border="0" />
<div id="section2">
<p>For over 15 years <span>Cinemuze</span> has had the honor of working with some of the most talented creative collaborators tulsa has to offer. We love working on a variety of projects. As it is our goal to be a well rounded company with our fingers in a lot of pies.</p>
<p>Our paramount value is to approach the material with excellence, and an original point of view to tell a unique and compelling story. It is our belief that life is what you make of it, and the saddest lost is not to explore all your potential in the short time you've been given.</p>
<p>We've had the opportunity to work on multiple feature films and national television shows ranging from christian television to TLC television. We've created multiple award winning music vidoes, short films and even a feature film. Feel free to take a look around the site, and drop us an email, we look forward to hearing from you.</p> 
<a href="mailto:titusjackson@mac.com"><img src="images/email1.png" alt="email" width="26" height="26" /></a>
</div> 
</div>
<div id="projects">
<h5>View our current projects:</h5>

 <div class="wrapper1">
 <iframe width="265" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8CZJzUk7fFM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 <p>Eugene Gregory Promo</p>
 </div>
 <div id="wrapper2">
 <iframe width="265" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cLm3Vh4_Ruc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 <p>Family Cup Promo</p>
 </div>
 <div class="wrapper3">
 <iframe width="265" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2t9-vVNgF7c" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 <p>This Generation</p>
 </div>
 </div>
<div id="contact">
 <section3>
<h3>To connect with Us:</h3>
<p><span>Cinemuze</span> is based in Tulsa, Oklahoma and travels widely for a variety of projects.</p>
<p>If your interested in our work, you can connect with us via email or phone.</p>
</section3>
<div class="section4">
<img src="images/email1.png" alt="email" width="26" height="26" />
<a href="mailto:titusjackson@mac.com">
<p>titusjackson@mac.com</p>
</a><img src="images/phone.png" alt="phone" width="24" height="24" />
<p>+1 (918) 671-3340</p>
</div>
</div>
<footer>
</footer>

</body>
</html>


@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
body {
    font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #42413C;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
}


#header {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -15px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}

div#header nav {
    width: 1425;
    height: 110px;
}

div#header ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 100px;
    float: left;
}

div#header li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 64px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

div#header a {
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
     line-height: 45px;
     font-size: .9em;
     text-transform: capitalize;
}

div#header a:hover {
    color: rgba(249,0,3,1.00);
}

div#styledimg {
    background-image: url(images/logo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 224px;
    height: 85px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    z-index: 1003;
}


/*page-specific header styles*/

#header {
    background-color: rgba(60,59,59,1.00);
    width: 1425;
    height: 110px;
}

/* layout styles*/

/*home page*/

.slideshow {
    background-image:url(images/pic3.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 500px 0px 0px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 900px;
    line-height: 0px;
    margin-top: -330px;
    padding-top: -15px;
}

#header {
    background-color: transparent;
}

#head-soc {
    width: 129;
    height: 86;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-top: 255px;
    right: 25px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
}

#head-soc a {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

 #linkedin-icon a {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 43px;
    width: 43px;
    border: 0;
    background-image: url(images/socialsprites_white.png); 
    display: block;
    float: right;   
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
#linkedin-icon a:hover {
    background-image: url(images/socialsprites_white.png); 
    background-position: 0px -43px;
}

#youtube-icon a {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 43px;
    width: 43px;
    border: 0;
    background-image: url(images/socialsprites_white.png); 
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background-position: -43px 0px;
}

 #youtube-icon a:hover {
    background-image: url(images/socialsprites_white.png); 
    background-position: -43px -43px;
}

 #facebook-icon a {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 43px;
    width: 43px;
    border: 0;
    background-image: url(images/socialsprites_white.png);
    display: block;
    float: right;
    background-position: -86px -85px;
}

 #facebook-icon a:hover {
    background-image: url(images/socialsprites_white.png);
    background-position: -86px -128px;
}

.content p {
    font-family: BlairMdITC TT-Medium;
    font-size: 44px;
    line-height: 120%;
    width: 550px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 360px;
    margin-top: 330px;
    margin-left: 575px;
    color: rgba(248,241,241,1.00);
}

/* about page*/

div#about {
     background-color:rgba(188,184,184,1.00);
     height: 550px;
     margin-top: -35px;
     padding-top: 100px;
 }

.wrapper h4 {
    font-famiy: Geneva;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-left: 224px;
    color: rgba(249,0,3,1.00);
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}

.wrapper p {
    font-family: Geneva;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 226px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    color: rgba(134,133,133,1.00);
}

h6 {
    padding-left: 225px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: rgba(60,59,59,1.00);
}
img {
     float: left;
     margin-left: 225px;
     margin-right: 15px;
 }

#section2 {
     font-family: Helvetica;
     font-size: 16px;
     color: rgba(60,59,59,1.00);
     width: 1280px;
     padding-top: -80px;
     height: 300px;
 }

 #section2 p {
     color: rgba(60,59,59,1.00);
 }

#section2 img {
    margin-left: 2px;   
}

span {
     color: rgba(249,0,3,1.00);
 }


 /* projects page */

 div#projects {
     background-color: #3A3939;
     background-position: 25px;
     height: 450px;
     margin: 0px; 
     line-height: 0;
     padding-top: 25px; 
 }

 .wrapper1 {
     float: left;
     width: 265;
     height: 200px;
     margin-left: 200px;
     padding-top: 50px;
 }

 #wrapper2 {
     float: right;
     width: 265;
     height: 200px;
     margin-right: 200px;
     padding-top: 50px;
 }

 .wrapper3 {
     float: left;
     margin-left: 175px;
     padding-top: 50px;
     width: 265;
     height: 200px;
 } 

 .wrapper1 p {
    margin-left: 42px;
    font-family: BlairMdITC TT-Medium;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: rgba(249,0,3,1.00);
    margin-top: 20px;
 }

 #wrapper2 p {
     margin-left: 65px;
     font-family: BlairMdITC TT-Medium;
     font-size: 20px;
     color: rgba(249,0,3,1.00);
     margin-top: 20px;
 }

 .wrapper3 p {
     margin-left: 70px;
     font-family: BlairMdITC TT-Medium;
     font-size: 20px;
     color: rgba(249,0,3,1.00);
     margin-top: 20px;
 }

  div#projects h5 {
    margin-left: 650px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color:rgba(179,178,178,1.00);
    padding-bottom: 45px;


    margin-bottom: -15px;

 }

 p {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 195px;
    color: rgba(249,247,247,1.00);
 }

 /* contact page */

 div#contact {
     background-image:url(images/studio4.png);
     background-size: cover;
     background-attachment: fixed;
     padding-top: 35px;
     padding-bottom: 100px; 
 }

 section3 h3 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: rgba(249,0,3,1.00);
    margin-left: 660px;
    margin-top: 75px;
 }

 section3 p {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
    width: 650px;
    padding-left: 85px;
    margin-left: 385px;
 }

 .section4 {
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
    margin-left: 440px;
    margin-top: 50px;
 }

 .section4 a {
     text-decoration: none;
 }

 .section4 a p:hover {
     color: rgba(249,0,3,1.00);
}




/* ~~ The footer ~~ */




/*HTML 5 support - Sets new HTML 5 tags to display:block so browsers know how to render the tags properly. */
header, section, footer, aside, article, figure {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: By fixing your code... Btw, we need to see code to reply.

Comment: <div id="home">
<div class="slideshow">
<div id="header">
 <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="styledimg"></div>
</nav>

Comment: I have tried to add an image of my code but having difficulties doing so.

Comment: Ok, from what i can see, you didn't closed slideshow div? <div class="slideshow"> <div id="header"> ?  Try this: <div class="slideshow"></div>, and then open header div...

Comment: what I posted was just a part of the html code.

Comment: </div>
<div id="head-soc">
<div id="linkedin-icon"><a href="http://linkedin.com/pub/titus-jackson/2/a2b/939">Linkedin</a></div>
<div id="youtube-icon"><a href="http://youtube.com/titusishmael">Youtube</a></div>
<div id="facebook-icon"><a href="http://facebook.com/titusjackson1">Facebook</a></div>
</div> 
<div class="content">
<p>Create, Collaborate, Innovate</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

Comment: it's a one page website I'm working on

Comment: Test link would be fine. Also, place your HTML/CSS and javascript/jquery in your question - edit question, and you will find way to add core there - code in comments is basically unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

You've placed all of your HTML inside of the div with the slideshow class:

```
<div class="slideshow"> //this is left open
//other divs are closed later on like this one:
<div id="styledimg"></div>
//but all the divs below slideshow are inside of the slideshow div
```

So whatever animations you're doing to the slideshow div, will affect all of its children.

Comment: okay, I adjusted it in HTML like so: <div class="slideshow"></div> but I can't get my header, header-social and my paragraph to show.

Comment: Thanks, I did figure it out.